# Ember params and model are nil in afterModel hook when using dynamic segments id

Tags: ember.js

I have a router that looks like this:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('foo', { path: 'foo/:foo_id' }, function() {
  ...
  }
});
```

When I visit `/foo/1` it correctly loads the model automatically and displays. However, I wanted to use the `afterModel` hook to make some redirections ([reference](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/redirection/)). For debugging I did this:

```
App.FooIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   afterModel: function(model, transition) {
      console.log(model); // This returns `undefined`
   }
});
```

But it logs `undefined`.

I then tried manually checking the params in the model:

```
App.FooIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   ...
   model: function(params) {
     console.log(params); // This returns an empty queryParams object
   }
});
```

But that logs the `queryParams` object with no ID in it.

I understand that I may be misinterpreting where the dynamic segment ID is accessible, for instance is it only accessible from the `FooRoute`? If so, why would you ever use that route for anything considering you have the `FooIndexRoute`?

And above all, shouldn't the `afterModel` hook be logging the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right on, they are only accessible from the `FooRoute`

```
App.FooRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   ...
   model: function(params) {
     console.log(params); 
   }
});
```

The `FooRoute` is the actual route associated with the resource foo here.

```
this.resource('foo', { path: 'foo/:foo_id' }, function() {
  // this.route('index');  // free route defined by Ember
  ...
}
```

`FooIndexRoute` is merely a route below the resource that's hit when you hit the root of that resource.  In other words if you just hit `/foo/123` Ember is going render the `foo` template with the `foo/index` template in the `{{outlet}}`.  This is useful when you want to show something different when at the root of the resource vs when you are viewing a different route/resource under the resource.

For example imagine the use case where you are view a collection of posts.  You first visit `/posts` and in the index route it shows a list of the posts that you can click on to view a single post.  Once they click the post you want your url to show `/posts/1` but you don't want to show the list of posts anymore, you just want to show that single post.  The code would be something like this.

#### Router

```
this.resource('posts',  function() {
  this.route('view',{ path: ':id' });  
}
```

#### Posts template

```
<h1> Posts </h1>
{{outlet}}
```

#### Posts/index template

```
... show all posts here ...
```

#### Posts/view template

```
... show selected post here ...
```

PS there is no model associated with the `FooIndexRoute` only with the `FooRoute`, which is why the `afterModel` has nothing.

Comment: Using the `afterModel` hook in `FooRoute` worked, I initially forgot to use `.get()`. Thank you for explaining!